# Firebase Firestore onSnapshot gets null when used firestore FieldValue for Timestamp

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want to use my firestore time for my chat app. I coded below code but there is a problem about firestore Field Value.

I send my message to firestore like:

```
chatsRef.add({
  ...m,
  createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
});
```

Everything works correctly but when I listen(onSnapshot) the document that refers `chatsRef` the `createdAt` value always gets null also when I checked firestore the time correctly set. I think there is an async event in there and I have to wait for it. How can I fix that problem?

The `chatsRef`:

```
const chatsRef= db.collection("ChatRooms").doc(id).collection("Chat")
```

I listen the chatsRef with that code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let x = null;
    const unsubscribe = chatsRef
      .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
      .limit(10)
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        const messagesFirestore = querySnapshot
          .docChanges()
          .filter(({ type }) => type === "added")
          .map(({ doc }) => {
            const message = doc.data();
            x = message;
            console.log(x);// I checked my code and the object's createdAt field gets null.
            return { ...message, createdAt: message.createdAt.toDate() };
          });

        appendMessages(messagesFirestore);

       // Some irrelevant codes

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);
```

Also my message JSON structure is :

```
Object {
  "_id": "a51d2e86-df8d-449e-b41e-73fbd746856f",
  "createdAt": t {
"nanoseconds": 26000000,
"seconds": 1616336752
},
  "text": "1111",
  "user": Object {
    "_id": "jack1212312",
    "name": "jackAndME",
  },
}
```

Last changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let x = null;
    const unsubscribe = chatsRef
      .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
      .limit(10)
      .onSnapshot({ includeMetadataChanges: true }, (querySnapshot) => {
        const messagesFirestore = querySnapshot
          .docChanges()
          .filter(({ type }) => type === "added")
          .map(({ doc }) => {
            const message = doc.data();

            if (!doc.metadata.hasPendingWrites) {
              x = message;
              return { ...message, createdAt: message.createdAt.toDate() };
            }

            return null;
          });
        if (messagesFirestore[0]) {
          appendMessages(messagesFirestore);

          if (latestMessage.current != null) {
            if (
              new Date(
                latestMessage.current["createdAt"]["seconds"] * 1000 +
                  latestMessage.current["createdAt"]["nanoseconds"] / 1000000
              ) >
              new Date(
                x["createdAt"]["seconds"] * 1000 +
                  x["createdAt"]["nanoseconds"] / 1000000
              )
            ) {
              latestMessage.current = x;
            }
          } else {
            latestMessage.current = x;
          }
        }
      });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);
```

Note: Now, i can detect the metadata but i can not access the last version of the data by using snapshot.

Firebase doc says that :

```
1- A change event is immediately fired with the new data. The document has not yet been written to the backend so the "pending writes" flag is true.
2- The document is written to the backend.
3- The backend notifies the client of the successful write. There is no change to the document data, but there is a metadata change because the "pending writes" flag is now false.
```

But i can not access the pendingwrites flag when metadata written to backend without refreshing the page the snapshot did not get the data.

Comment: Have you tried to call the function with async await already?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean? Can you explain a little bit more?@LaravDev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to what Firebase calls ["latency compensation"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-local-changes):

> Local writes in your app will invoke snapshot listeners immediately.
> This is because of an important feature called "latency compensation."
> When you perform a write, your listeners will be notified with the new
> data before the data is sent to the backend.

Your snapshot is triggered before leaving your app, and the field for the timestamp will be `null`, then it will be triggered again after reaching the backend with the timestamp set.

To differentiate between the two, use the field `metadata.hasPendingWrites` as described in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for help. I can now detect the metadata but how can i get the last version of data( after writing backend) because i can detect the change but i can not access the last version data. I also added my last code. Also i added i quotation from firebase.

Comment: The document is "modified" after reaching the backend, so remove the filtering on "added" documents and you will see it

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter, you can prevent it from listening to snapshots which have pending writes; this can also save Firestore document reads.

Please take a look at my example for reference:

```
var collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Chats')
    .doc(chat.chatID)
    .collection('Messages')
    .orderBy('messageTimestamp', descending: true)
    .limit(30);

// Set up a snapshot listener and store the subscription
_chatMessagesCollectionSubsription = collectionReference
    .snapshots()
    .where((event) => !event.metadata
        .hasPendingWrites) // Don't want to listen to the pending writes because will get error on datetime
    .listen((QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) async {
      // Read you snapshot where snapshot.metadata.hasPendingWrite will always be false
    }
```